# Responsive Internet Explorer 8 Web site using ASP.NET

Tags: html, css, asp.net, responsive-design, xhtml

I am creating a responsive web site using asp.net and my target browser is Internet Explorer8 since the future user of my project is using Internet Explorer 8.

I'm having a problem in setting all my input fields into same width. Though i set the width into "90%" each of them they still showing different width. Does anyone can help me?

Pls see the photo.

This is what happen in my dropdownlist. The text had been cut base on the wodth size of dropdown.

[image: dropdwonlist]

And this is what i want to do. It is working fine in Chrome but not in Internet Explorer 8. 
[image: chromepreview]

And here is what i have so far.

**CSS**

```
*
            {
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
            }

            html
            {
                overflow:auto;
            }

            html, body
            {
                margin:auto;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                margin:auto;
                background:#ddd;
            }

            .placeholder
            {
                color:#aaa;
            }

            .main
            {
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }

            .nav
            {
                width:9%;
                min-width:9%;
                background:#111;
                text-align: center;
                position:absolute;
            }

            .panel
            {
                min-height:100%;
            }

            .nav ul
            {
                margin-top:110%;
            }

            .nav ul a
            {
                text-decoration:none;
                border:none;
            }

            a img
            {
                border:0;
                outline:none;

            }

            a:active, a:focus
            {
                outline:none;
                border:none;
            }


            .nav li
            {
                display:block;
                float:center;
                color:#fff;
                text-align:center;
            }


            .nav #logout, #add, #view, #setting
            {
                border-bottom:1px solid #3a3a3a;
            }

            .nav #add
            {
                border-top:1px solid #3a3a3a;
            }

            .nav li:hover
            {
                background:#333;

            }

            .nav li img
            {
                padding:20px 0 20px 0;
                height:55%;
                width:55%;
            }

            .nav_text
            {
                color:#777;
                font-family:helvetica;
                font-size: 70%;
                text-align:center;
                margin-top:-10px;
                text-indent:-5px;
                margin-bottom:5px;
            }

            .main_bar
            {
                width:100%;
                display:inline-block;
                margin-right:3%;
                background:#fff;
                float:right;
                width:75%;
                border-bottom:10px solid #3498db;
                margin-top:10px;
                background:rgba(255,255,255,1);
                box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0 1px 4px 0;
                border-bottom:10px solid #0dabc9;
                /*zoom: 1;
                filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#c0c0c0, Strength=8, Direction=0),
                       progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#c0c0c0, Strength=8, Direction=90),
                       progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#c0c0c0, Strength=8, Direction=180),
                       progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#c0c0c0, Strength=8, Direction=300);
                */
            }

            .tool_bar
            {
                width:10%;
                background:#333;
                height:50px;
                float:right;
                position:relative;
                margin-right:2%;
                margin-top:10px;
                border-top:30px solid #3498db;
            }

            .second_bar
            {
                display:block;
                margin-right:15%;
                background:#fff;
                float:right;
                width:75%;
                border-bottom:10px solid #3498db;
                margin-top:10px;
                background:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
                box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0 1px 4px 0;
                border-bottom:10px solid #0dabc9;
                zoom:1;
                filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#c0c0c0, Strength=8, Direction=0),
                       progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#c0c0c0, Strength=8, Direction=90),
                       progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#c0c0c0, Strength=8, Direction=180),
                       progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#c0c0c0, Strength=8, Direction=300);
            }

            .draft
            {   
                font-weight:bold;
                font-size:11px;
                font-family:Helvetica;
                color:#555;
                padding:1%;
                border:0px solid black;
                width:20%;

            }

            .draft span
            {
                display:inline-block;
                width:14%;
                border:1px solid #2980b9;
                padding:1%;
                border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;
                /*background:#bdc3c7;*/
                background:#2980b9;

            }

            .draft span img
            {
                vertical-align:bottom;
                width:16px;
                height:16px;
                padding:0px 5px;
            }

            .draft input[type=textbox]
            {
                /*position:absolute;*/
                border:1px solid #b0b0b0;
                border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
                padding:2%;
                width:65%;
                padding-left:5%;
            }


            .draft input[type=textbox]:focus
            {
                outline:none;
            }

            #Inner_Right_Layout {
                background-color: #43BDA4;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;    
                border: 0;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;

            }
            #control_main_div {
                height: 50%;
                width: 70%;
                margin-left: 0%;
                margin-top: 0%;
                border:1px solid black;
            }
            .username_div {
                height: 15%;
                width: 95%;
                margin: 0px;
                border:1px solid #aaa; 
                padding-bottom:5px;
            }

            .usr_img_div {
                width: 90%;
                float: left;
                border:;1px solid #2980b9;
                background:#2980b9;
                padding:3px;
            }

            .usrnm_txtbx_div {

                width: 95%;
                margin-left: 0%;
                font-family: Ubuntu;
                border:1px solid #aaa;
                margin-top:0%;

            }

            .usrnm_ddl_div
            {
                max-width:50%;
                margin-left:0%;
                font-family:Ubuntu;
                border:0;
                margin-top:0%;
            }

            .ddlprop
            {
                height:95%;
                width:95%;
                margin:0;
                padding:6px;
                border:0;
                margin-left:1px;
                font-family:'Ubuntu';
                font-size:16px;
            }
            .textprop {
                height: 95%;
                width: 95%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 6px;
                border: 0;
                margin-left: 1px;
                font-family: 'Ubuntu';
                font-size: 16px;
                font-weight: 100;
            }

            img
            {
                height:18px;
                width:18px;
                padding:4px;
            }

            .textfield
            {
                padding-top:10px;
            }

            .main_bar table
            {
                margin-top:3%;
                margin-left:3%;
                margin-bottom:3%;
            }

            td
            {
                padding-top:10px;
            }
```

**XHTML**

```
            <body>
                <form id="form1" runat="server">

                <div class = "main">
                <div class = "nav panel">
                <ul>
                <li id = "add"><a href = "#"><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl = "~/images/add.PNG" /><p class = "nav_text">ADD</p></a></li>
                <li id = "view"><a href = "#"><asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl = "~/images/view2.PNG" /><p class = "nav_text">VIEW</p></a></li>
                <li id = "setting"><a href = "#"><asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl = "~/images/setting1.PNG" /><p class = "nav_text">SETTING</p></a></li>
                <li id = "Li1"><a href = "#"><asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" ImageUrl = "~/images/logout1.PNG" /><p class = "nav_text">LOGOUT</p></a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>

                <div class = "tool_bar"></div>

                <div class = "main_bar">
                <table>
                <tr>

                <td><div class = "usr_img_div"><asp:Image ID="Image5" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/adver.PNG" /></div></td>
                        <td class = "textfield"><div class = "usrnm_txtbx_div">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" CssClass="ddlprop">
                            <asp:ListItem>sample text</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>This is a long text and what im trying to do is to set the max-width.</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div></td>

                        <td><div class = "usr_img_div"><asp:Image ID="Image7" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/adver.PNG" /></div></td>
                        <td class = "textfield"><div class = "usrnm_txtbx_div">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" CssClass="ddlprop">
                            <asp:ListItem>sample text</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>This is a long text and what im trying to do is to set the max-width.</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div></td>

                        <td><div class = "usr_img_div"><asp:Image ID="Image6" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/adver.PNG" /></div></td>
                        <td class = "textfield"><div class = "usrnm_txtbx_div"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass = "textprop"></asp:TextBox></div></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                        <td><div class = "usr_img_div"><asp:Image ID="Image8" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/adver.PNG" /></div></td>
                        <td class = "textfield"><div class = "usrnm_txtbx_div">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="ddlprop">
                            <asp:ListItem>sample text</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>This is a long text and what im trying to do is to set the max-width.</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div></td>

                        <td><div class = "usr_img_div"><asp:Image ID="Image9" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/adver.PNG" /></div></td>
                        <td class = "textfield"><div class = "usrnm_txtbx_div"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass = "textprop"></asp:TextBox></div></td>

                        <td><div class = "usr_img_div"><asp:Image ID="Image10" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/adver.PNG" /></div></td>
                        <td class = "textfield"><div class = "usrnm_txtbx_div"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" CssClass = "textprop"></asp:TextBox></div></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td><div class = "usr_img_div"><asp:Image ID="Image11" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/adver.PNG" /></div></td>
                        <td class = "textfield"><div class = "usrnm_txtbx_div">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" CssClass="ddlprop">
                            <asp:ListItem>sample text</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>This is a long text and what im trying to do is to set the max-width.</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div></td>

                       <td><div class = "usr_img_div"><asp:Image ID="Image12" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/adver.PNG" /></div></td>
                        <td class = "textfield"><div class = "usrnm_txtbx_div"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" CssClass = "textprop"></asp:TextBox></div></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td><div class = "usr_img_div"><asp:Image ID="Image13" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/adver.PNG" /></div></td>
                        <td class = "textfield"><div class = "usrnm_txtbx_div">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" CssClass="ddlprop">
                            <asp:ListItem>sample text</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>This is a long text and what im trying to do is to set the max-width.</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div></td>

                        <td><div class = "usr_img_div"><asp:Image ID="Image14" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/adver.PNG" /></div></td>
                        <td class = "textfield"><div class = "usrnm_txtbx_div">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6" runat="server" CssClass="ddlprop">
                            <asp:ListItem>sample text</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>This is a long text and what im trying to do is to set the max-width.</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div></td>

                </tr>
                </table>
                </div>

                </div>
                </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Why do you need a responsive design when your target browser is IE8?

Comment: Hi @Mike W because most of my users are olders and their Computer are set into lower resolution using IE that's why i been finding a way to do it in IE.

Comment: could you get me fiddle to work on ?? and what exactly this mean "Though i set the width into "90%" each of them they still showing different width."

Comment: Hi @Manjuboyz. I think i can't get you fiddle because the code i use in this post is asp.net fiddle is only accepting html tags. :(

Comment: Actually I implemented,it on my system, since I have IE 11 it seems to work fine

Comment: Oh ok. But im been trying to do it in IE 8 do you have any ideas or hack to do it in IE 8?

Comment: what is the screen resolution of the first pic you have taken, is there anything to do with that ??(since you said it is responsive website )

Comment: No. both in the pictures are in the same resolution. The first picture is in IE browser and the last one is run in chrome. the said responsive is different issue in the drop down list.

Comment: try giving 100% width to .textfield, since it is td, let me know any differences ?

Comment: I feel there is too many css class file in single td!!, and no body using IE8 over here to find out the differences

Comment: Sorry @Manjuboyz does i feel you bad? Im sorry about it. I'd just talk to my users and found out they'd been using IE10 not 8 sorry :(

Comment: There is nothing bad in knowing,we all here to learn and explore, cheers :), so what now, does it works or still stuck with the problem ??

Comment: Wait i will try it. and beep you back if i'd encounter another problem.. thanks @Manjuboyz for helping me :))) your such a great person :)

Comment: By the way, you say you're using XHTML, but IE8 doesn't do XHTML. So you mean HTML after all, do you?